# What are these seed-like spots on my oranges?

Tags: orange

My oranges have these strange brown things on their skin. They look like seeds or perhaps parasites. What are these?

[image: Orange]

**Edit:** As suggested by @RohitGupta, I've added a close-up photo of the "bugs". Here, the things look more like bugs.

[image: Close-up]

Comment: They are not seeds,  They look like bugs to me.  Try prying one out and get a closeup photo.

Comment: @RohitGupta I've added a closeup photo as you suggested. Still don't know what these are though.

Comment: looks like some sort of mite or leach, or like those weird bumps you find on tree leaves but smaller and longer

Answer (score 2):

If most of the fruit is so heavily embedded by the bugs then you cant remove them from these fruits very easily.

I would try to save the next lot of fruit by spraying with an insecticide and/or some sort of oil (such as mineral oil or Conquer Oil from yates).  I am not associated with Yates.  Insecticide before flowering and Oil before fruiting.